# De Sitter horizon area increase

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, de-sitter-spacetime

Black holes increase area when any object falls past the horizon. Note: We define "when" as when the [hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem) from the object falling in becomes undetectable for distant observers. It would also be possible to define "when" as the time that the entire mass-energy of the object, somehow converted into a single photon at the right location just outside the horizon, would reach a distant observer with so much redshift that it would become indistinguishable from Hawking radiation. Both of these processes happen fairly quickly.

This increase in area corresponds to an increase in entropy and occurs even if [the black hole loses mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_process) in the process. It will increase entropy more than the entropy in the object falling in.

Assuming that the cosmological constant stays constant (even though it [may have not been constant in the past](https://astrobites.org/2021/05/17/template-post-5/)), the final state of the universe is the [de Sitter spacetime metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_space). Like an inside-out black hole, it has a de Sitter horizon that radiates Hawking radiation and objects falling beyond it are lost. Sadly, we permanently lost [97% of the observable universe](https://www.forbes.com/sites/ethansiegel/2015/06/08/dark-energy-renders-97-of-the-galaxies-in-our-observable-universe-permanently-unreachable/?sh=29ea75115983) so far.

Suppose in the far future there is an isolated planet that sends an unmanned rocket out beyond the de Sitter horizon. Does the horizon grow in area like a black hole horizon would? My reasoning is that the mass of the planet is a correction term that very slightly reduces the area of the de Sitter horizon and the rocket launch steals a tiny amount of mass from the planet. Is this correct?

Comment: You can't quite think of the de Sitter horizon in the same way as the Schwarzschild horizon.  The reason for this is that the de Sitter spacetime is homogenous and static.  So, the horizon is associated with an "observation" point, and no two spatially seperated observers will agree on where the horizon is.  This is different from a black hole horizon, whose location is agreed upon by all observers.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: I guess the horizon as measured from the planet? It would be the same on any point of the planet, although the center-of-mass of the planet is the only inertial frame we can use.

Comment: If you're interested in an indirect argument based on thermodynamic properties of the de Sitter horizon, then you may be able to infer the answer from Bousso's exceptionally readable review *Adventures in de Sitter space* ([arXiv:hep-th/0205177](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0205177)).